# How do I fix this issue with the if statements inside this for loop?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

```
#define MAX 100000

bool hasPair(int array[], int start, int end, int size, int number)
{
 int i, temp;
bool binMap[MAX] = {0}; /*initialize hash map as 0*/

for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
 {
   temp = number - array[i];

if((temp>=0 && binMap[temp] == 1) && (temp != array[i]) && (array[i]>=start && array[i]<=end))
{
  printf("The array contains at least one pair which sums up to %d.\n",number); // problem here
  return true;
}
binMap[array[i]] = 1;

if(binMap[temp] == 0 && binMap[array[i]] == 0) //and here
{
   printf("The array does not contain any pair which sums up to %d.",number);
   return false;

  }
}
}
```

I need to write a function which gets an array,its size,the range of its elements(start and end) and a random number as input and the output must be a statement whether there is a pair of different numbers inside the array that their sum equals that random number that we entered as input.I have a problem with the if statements,
because for example:-

an array of 10 elements and the range of these elements is 0-10 the random number is 18 and the arrays elements are:- 0,5,5,2,9,8,2,7,8,2.There wont be any combination of sum between two different numbers of this array which gives us 18
and it works fine in the functions I wrote.

The problem is that for example if we took the same array and this time we substituted 18 for 10 then there will be two different numbers that their sum will be equal to 10 but in my function if I enter this array with random number as 10 then it wont work and I think there is a problem with my If statement so if you can see it whats the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is in the 2nd `if` condition. It's redundant. You are always invoking this case after the first iteration, and you don't go on for the next iterations.

You should remove the 2nd if condition entirely, and instead add AFTER the `for` loop a simple statement: `return false;`.

The idea is you should let the algorithm keep going to the next iterations, even if one was unseccesful. You only return `false` when you are done with the loop without finding matching elements during it - and only now you can tell no such elements exist.